# How do I split a line and extract values from it in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble coding part of a program that will read in a name and 10 numbers from a file. The fie is called grades.dat The structure of the data file is:

```
Number One
99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99
John Doe
90 99 98 89 87 90.2 87 99 89.3 91
Clark Bar
67 77 65 65.5 66 72 78 62 61 66
Scooby Doo
78 80 77 78 73 74 75 75 76.2 69
```

This is all I have for the function to get the data and I'm not even sure if that's right.

```
void input (float& test1, float& test2, float& test3, float& test4, float& test5, float& test6, float& test7, float& test8, float& test9, float& test10, string& studentname)
{
  ifstream infile;

  infile.open ("grades.dat");
  if (infile.fail())
    {
      cout << "Could not open file, please make sure it is named correctly (grades.dat)" << "\n" << "and that it is in the correct spot. (The same directory as this program." << "\n";
      exit(0);
    }
  getline (infile, studentname);
  return;
}
```

Comment: `90.2` is not an integer. Did you mean that it's supposed be a name followed by ten *numbers*? If not, how is your program expected to handle malformed input?

Comment: yes it was, my fault. Edited question. Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the standard C++ idiom, reading two lines at a time (or failing if this isn't possible):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include <iterator>  // only for note #1
#include <vector>    //     -- || --

int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");
    std::string name, grade_line;

    while (std::getline(infile, name) && std::getline(infile, grade_line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(grade_line);

        // See #1; otherwise:

        double d;

        while (iss >> d)
        {
            // process grade
        }
    }
}
```

Note: If the sole purpose of he inner loop (marked `#1`) is to store all the grades, then as @Rob suggests you can use stream iterators:

```
std::vector<double> grades (std::istream_iterator<double>(iss),
                            std::istream_iterator<double>());
```

The stream iterator does the same thing as the inner `while` loop above, i.e. it iterates over tokens of type `double`. You might like to insert the entire vector into a large container that holds pairs `std::pair<std::string, std::vector<double>>` of names and grades.

Comment: Or `std::vector<double> v((std::istream_iterator<double>(iss)), std::istream_iterator<double>());` instead of the inner while loop.

Comment: @Sam - the `&&` operator executes left-to-right. So it reads `name` first, then (only if reading `name` succeeded) it reads `grade_line`.

Comment: @Rob: Good thinking; if storage in a vector is indeed the goal, then I'm all in favour of the stream iterator. Let me edit.

Comment: this doesnt work. I just made a quick file pasted this in, added missing needed components and changed the input file to the one im using and all it does is output the first line of numbers. I need it to output all the lines

Comment: @Sam: Works fine for me. Is your input file exactly as in your question? What "components" where missing? This compiles fine as presented...